# ¿Cómo puedo colocar la primera letra mayúsculas y las demás minúsculas?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Estoy trabajando con SQL Server y me salió la duda.

¿Cómo puedo generar la primera letra en mayúsculas, y las demás en minúsculas?

Sé que para Oracle existe `initcap()` y se escribe del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT 
     initcap(columna1)
    ,initcap(columna2)
FROM tabla
```

Pero no he encontrado nada similar para SQL Server.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: INITCAP cambia **todas las primeras letras de una frase en mayúsculas  no solo la primera letra.** Si quieres una función que emule a INITCAP la tienes en mi respuesta. Si quieres una función que cambie solamente la primera letra puedes modificar la misma función haciendo que evalúe sola la primera palabra de la cadena. La función es resistente a datos problemáticos tales como cadenas que empiezan con espacios o caracteres especiales.

Comment: la pero la pregunta es como le paso el nombre del campo a la funcion no un texto cualquiera

Answer (score 4):

Puedes probar con:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(columna1, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(columna1, 2, LEN(columna1)))
FROM [tutabla]
```

**EDICIÓN**

Puedes ver la demostracion de mi respuesta [aquí](http://rextester.com/JKAP41847).

Comment: Buena respuesta

Comment: Gracias compa!, espero que solucione el problema!

Comment: A modo de complementar tu respuesta, acá hay un ejemplo del funcionamiento de tu solución http://rextester.com/JKAP41847 para que lo pongas como demostración si así lo deseas :)

Comment: Gracias @Flxtr :D

Comment: -1 No sirve si la cadena empieza por un espacio o por caracteres especiales .

Comment: @A.Cedano perfecto, Ahora mi respuesta es mala y no resuelve el problema que el Op describe? Creo que mi respuesta es correcta y la tuya igual salvo que la tuya puede ser mas completa. No veo el -1 valido. Saludos

Comment: @A.Cedano parece ser que eres el único que la respuesta es mala, ai resuelve de alguna forma l problema del OP no hay porque tomarselo personal

Comment: No hay nada personal. Le he dado -1 para que mejores la respuesta la cual se queda a medio camino por lo que ya he explicado: si la cadena tiene un espacio en blanco al inicio o cualquier carácter especial tu respuesta es sencillamente inútil. Si la mejoras retiraré el -1. En cuanto a la mía si eres tú quien ha votado en contra tendrías que explicar el motivo por el que lo has hecho. Yo he votado en contra y he dicho por qué lo he hecho. Saludos.

Comment: No he votado en contra, te dije que si el OP necesitaba lo que tu dejaste era la correcta. El OP puso claramente la primera letra del valor, probablemente no sabia todo lo que hacia con `INITCAP` pero lo que el queria era otra cosa. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Te recuerdo que `INITCAP` en [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions065.htm) **cambia a mayúsculas todas las primeras letras de una cadena dada**.

> INITCAP returns char, with the first letter of each word in uppercase,
>   all other letters in lowercase. Words are delimited by white space or
>   characters that are not alphanumeric.

La función que emula a `INITCAP` en SQL Server es la siguiente.

Como podrás ver, la misma función evalúa si la letra a cambiar es alfanumérica o no antes de hacer el cambio, lo cual es muy útil en cadenas que empiecen por espacios o con carácteres especiales.

Todo lo demás está comentado en el mismo código.

[**VER DEMO:**](http://rextester.com/QQHC70461)

```
  -- Drop la función si existe
  IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.InitCap') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.InitCap;
  GO

 -- Implementando la función de Oracle INITCAP en SQL Server
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.InitCap (@inStr VARCHAR(8000))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
  AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @outStr VARCHAR(8000) = LOWER(@inStr),
         @char CHAR(1), 
         @alphanum BIT = 0,
         @len INT = LEN(@inStr),
                 @pos INT = 1;        

    -- Iterar entre todos los caracteres en la cadena de entrada
    WHILE @pos <= @len BEGIN

      -- Obtener el siguiente caracter
      SET @char = SUBSTRING(@inStr, @pos, 1);

      -- Si la posición del caracter es la 1ª, o el caracter previo no es alfanumérico
      -- convierte el caracter actual a mayúscula
      IF @pos = 1 OR @alphanum = 0
        SET @outStr = STUFF(@outStr, @pos, 1, UPPER(@char));

      SET @pos = @pos + 1;

      -- Define si el caracter actual es  non-alfanumérico
      IF ASCII(@char) <= 47 OR (ASCII(@char) BETWEEN 58 AND 64) OR
      (ASCII(@char) BETWEEN 91 AND 96) OR (ASCII(@char) BETWEEN 123 AND 126)
      SET @alphanum = 0;
      ELSE
      SET @alphanum = 1;

    END

   RETURN @outStr;         
  END
  GO

  -- Algunas pruebas ...
  SELECT dbo.InitCap('#estadoS uNIDOS dE aMÉRICA');
  SELECT dbo.InitCap(' estadoS uNIDOS dE aMÉRICA');
  SELECT dbo.InitCap('PAPA FRANCISCO');
```

**Resultado**

```
    prueba
1   #Estados Unidos De América

    prueba
1    Estados Unidos De América

    prueba
1   Papa Francisco
```

---

**Fuentes:**

- [INITCAP - Capitalize the First Letter - Oracle to SQL Server Migration](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/initcap)
- [InitCap / String Capitalization Function en SQL Server Helper](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/initcap.aspx)

Comment: A pesar de que el OP hace referencia a la función `INITCAP`, dice en su pregunta "* la primera letra en mayúsculas, y las demás en minúsculas*" y con esa función se estarían poniendo en mayúsculas la primera letra de todas las palabras, no solo de la primera.

Comment: @Flxtr la referencia a INITCAP es bastante clara y explícita en la pregunta. De todos modos si lo que se quiere es solo la primera letra sólo habría que modificar el WHILE. El problema de la otra respuesta es que no sirve si la cadena empieza por un espacio en blanco o por algún carácter especial. Esta respuesta emula el funcionamiento de INITCAP y modificándola haría una función que podríamos llamar INITWORDCAP para que ponga en mayúsculas solo la primera letra.

Answer (score 0):

Hice una adaptación de la solución del blog de [George Mastros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1408129/george-mastros): [LessThanDot](https://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/sql-server-proper-case-function) que encaja mejor con los caracteres hispanos, con tildes, ñ y demás:

```
CREATE Function InitCap(@dat varchar(8000)) returns varchar(8000) as
begin 
    declare   @pos smallint
            , @pat varchar(85) = '%[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                                   +'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]'
                                  +'[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%'
    select    @dat = stuff(lower(@dat), 1, 1, upper(left(@dat, 1)))
            , @pos = patindex(@pat, @dat collate Latin1_General_CS_AI)
    while @pos > 0
          select  @dat = stuff(@dat, @pos, 2, upper(substring(@dat, @pos, 2)))
                , @pos = patindex(@pat, @dat collate Latin1_General_CS_AI)
    return @dat
end
```

A efectos de mayúsculas y minúsculas, el patrón `[^A-Za-z]` o similares no funciona salvo en un `collate Latin1_General_BIN`, por lo que hay que ponerlo de la forma explícita que se muestra. Por lo demás, es bastante rápido.